# How to disable recreate fragment when rotate screen in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

In my application I used `NavigationComponent` for show `Fragments` and I used `ViewModel` !
But rotate the screen recreate fragment and remove all of position, recall again api and more...

My Fragment codes:

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    //Binding
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    @Inject
    lateinit var genreAdapter: GenreAdapter

    @Inject
    lateinit var topMoviesAdapter: TopMoviesAdapter

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //InitViews
        binding.apply {
            //Genres
            viewModel.genresList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                genreAdapter.differ.submitList(it)
                genresRecycler.initRecycler(
                    LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false),
                    genreAdapter
                )
            }
            viewModel.loadGenresList()
            //Top movies
            viewModel.topMoviesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                topMoviesAdapter.differ.submitList(it.data)
                topMoviesRecycler.initRecycler(
                    LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false),
                    topMoviesAdapter
                )
                topMoviesRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(4)
            }
            viewModel.loadTopMoviesList(1)
            //Loading
            viewModel.loading.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                if (it) {
                    homeLoading.showInvisible(true)
                } else {
                    homeLoading.showInvisible(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel codes:**

```
    @HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: HomeRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val genresList = MutableLiveData<List<ResponseGenres.ResponseGenresItem>>()
    val topMoviesList = MutableLiveData<ResponseMovies>()
    val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun loadGenresList() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = repository.genresList()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            genresList.postValue(response.body())
        }
    }

    fun loadTopMoviesList(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        loading.postValue(true)
        val response = repository.topMoviesList(id)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            topMoviesList.postValue(response.body())
        }
        loading.postValue(false)
    }
}
```

How can I fix it and disable recreate Fragment?

Comment: _"How can I fix it and disable recreate Fragment?"_ Sounds to me like you're going about this the wrong way. Part of the reason why you have a ViewModel is that it will survive orientation changes, so that the most recent state can be observed again in the newly created fragment.

Comment: @Michael , Thanks. but can you help me with codes? can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a suggestion to avoid re-call of the API, but never though about disable recreating the fragment in fragments as this an Android Architecture.

Simply, override the `onCreate()` method in the Fragment, and move calling API logic to it.

```
viewModel.loadGenresList()
```

This will call it once, as `onCreate()` is only created once even after screen rotation